# sdl2 ttf dll issue winwows mingw-w64

Tags: windows-10, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I've been trying to get the sdl2 ttf extension library to work. I am able to compile code without issue, but when running the exe, via command line, I get the following message popup. "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000007b). Click OK to close the application" searching for others with similar issues, it seems like the issue they had was that they had put the wrong version of the dll in their system32 directory, but I have tried putting both the 32 and 64 bit versions in and neither worked (the 64 bit one is what should work). Any ideas on what else could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was just that I didn't also copy over the libfreetype-6.dll